# Error while making connection on oracle sql developer using linux OS

Tags: linux, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to make a new connection on oracle sqldeveloper as sysdba and when i hit test or connect i got this error message:

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Comment: You haven't shown us the connection settings you're trying to use, or anything about the database and listener you're trying to connect to. Is the DB on the same machine you're running the client on? Is the listener up, and if so what address and port is it listening on? Is there a firewall between the client and server? Have you researched this at all - it's quite a common message...

Answer (score 0):

The default port is 1521, but 1522 is often common.

Check if the database is up.  database will not be up causing this issue. 
or Check if you are able to connect using sqlplus

Comment: So, i should change the port? @Somke